# Using the code from a tutorial?

Tags: copyright, patents

If there is a game programming tutorial incorporate a full, working example code of a specific algorithm, technology (ray-casting or parallax-scrolling...etc), but the author marks it with copyright, can it be used to develop a game then publish it? (maybe even for commercial uses)

( Sorry for language mistakes. )

*(( A tutorial teaches something...so is it even possible to make copyrighted someting which is published to show the exact way how to do something? ))*

Answer (score 1):

Copyright is about copying. You are not allowed to just copy the code from the book. You *are* allowed to read the book carefully, use the exercises to  practice your skills, and learn how to do the things the book teaches, and then do them.

Commercial or not makes no difference, except that damages may be higher for commercial use, and there are laws when copyright infringement becomes criminal, and commercial use makes that more likely.